# Передача jq объекта в функцию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не работает функция `setError`. вызывается из функции `getFormArray($form)` - $form форма где происходит поиск `input`.  Ошибка: `TypeError: $input.addClass is not a function`.

```
function setError($input) {
    /*var $par = $input.parents('.form-group');
    $par.addClass('has-error');*/
    $input.addClass('has-error');
}

function getFormArray($form) {
  // соберет объет вида {name: value, name: value}
  var formData = {};

  $form.find(':input').each(function() {
    value = $.trim(this.value);
    if (value.length == 0) {
        setError(this);
        throw new NoValue();
    } else
        formData[this.name] = value;
  });
  return formData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете в `setError` не объект-обертку jQuery, а DOM-элемент. Надо:

```
setError($(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` - это в данном случае DOM объект. Поэтому передавать нужно `$(this)`:

```
setError($(this));
```